# Jenkins claims build as Unstable though i see it passing

Tags: jenkins

I've a simple Jenkins job where i runt python script to run a bunch of tests. I see the build as UNSTABLE even i see no obvious errors in the Jenkins job as well as no tests failing.

Whats i'm running is python

I'm not using any external test framework like nose. Its just a python script.

Answer (score 1):

"Unstable" is the result Jenkins assigned when tests are failing. The only other way to get "Unstable" result is through the use of some post-build plugins. If you don't have any other plugins that are setting the build as unstable, then you have to take a closer look at all the tests.

If you paste the console output here, that would help as well

Comment: Find the snippet from the console logs on Jenkins towards the ends where the job failed